# i am using this => int get itemCount { return _items.length; } } problem is- it show number of products not quantity of the products

Tags: flutter, dart

this is an e commerce application
i added cartbutton on appBar and want to show total quantity number of products on it...
problem is- it show number of products not quantity of the products
what to use?

```
 void addItem(String productId, double price, String title) {
if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
  _items.update(
      productId,
      (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
          amount: existingCartItem.amount,
          id: existingCartItem.id,
          quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
          title: existingCartItem.title));
  print("update");
  notifyListeners();
} else {
  _items.putIfAbsent(
      productId,
      () => CartItem(
          amount: price,
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
          quantity: 1,
          title: title));
  print("add");
  notifyListeners();
}
```

}

Comment: Your code snippet does not contain any display logic. You only showed the code to add/update your cart items.

Where are you displaying your cart items? Have a look there, if you are calling something like `_items.length` instead of `item.quantity`

Comment: it is used to show in appBar in which i used shopping cart icon button and i used stack on it to display total quantity of product not total product i.e if total product if 4 then in my code it only shows 4. if 4 products which have different quantity so i want to show the quantity not number of products

Comment: Can you clarify what the difference is between "number of products" and "quantity of products"?  The number of products is a quantity.  Do you mean that you're showing the number of *different* products, but you want to show the sum of the quantities for all products?  You also haven't shown enough information for anyone to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your business needs in the application, you can display the required information

1. Number of Distinct Products in the list
2. Returning Total quantity of products added to the cart

For the first option

```
int distictProducts() {
   return _items.length;
}
```

For the second option

```
int totalQuantities() {
   int totalQuantitiesOfProducts = 0;
   _items.forEach((cartItems) {
      totalQuantitiesOfProducts += cartItems.quantity;
   });
   return totalQuantitiesOfProducts;
}
```